# Ошибка Slugify Function Autoslug

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки!

Выдает ошибку:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/DjangoProjects/blog_project/blog/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from blog.models import Posts, Category, StaticPage
  File "D:\DjangoProjects\blog_project\blog\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from autoslug import AutoSlugField
  File "C:\Users\Verchenko\d18\lib\site-packages\autoslug\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from autoslug.fields import AutoSlugField
  File "C:\Users\Verchenko\d18\lib\site-packages\autoslug\fields.py", line 29, in <module>
    from autoslug.settings import slugify, autoslug_modeltranslation_enable
  File "C:\Users\Verchenko\d18\lib\site-packages\autoslug\settings.py", line 64, in <module>
    slugify_function_path = getattr(settings, 'AUTOSLUG_SLUGIFY_FUNCTION', 'autoslug.utils.slugify')
  File "C:\Users\Verchenko\d18\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Verchenko\d18\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting AUTOSLUG_SLUGIFY_FUNCTION, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Не могу понять в чем дело! Уже в settings.py вставлял AUTOSLUG_SLUGIFY_FUNCTION = autoslug.utils.slugify, и pytils.translit.slugify. Но всё равно ошибку выдает. До этого было нормально всё, но после того как создал приложение для коомментариев блога, и форму. Сделал миграции, запускаю, и такие ошибки не пропадают. В модели комментариев, автослага не использовал. Натолкните на мысль, как может помочь исправить это.

settings.py

```html
"""
Django settings for blog_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import autoslug
import pytils

import blog

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'gb&19!s+y)8e&m9e5fyoob5jm1yxyox6i@&i)boh1stu2e#x=y'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'comments',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'blog.context_processors.getting_category_list',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Bishkek'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

import os
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static')
]
```

Comment: В ошибке написано в чем у вас проблема.

Comment: Я её не совсем пойму. Я не развертываю на сервере, поэтому по идеее DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODUL не нужно настраивать. Моожете объяснить?

Comment: Прикрепите ваш `settimgs.py`

Comment: Прикрепил в тело основного вопроса.